# How to apply the condition for two different array inside the objects using id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

new to `javascript` here, I have two different array inside the objects named `service_types` and `items`. In the first object `service_type` I have the array items as shown below

```
 "service_types": [
    {"id": 3,"name": "Engine Oil"},
    {"id": 4,"name": "Castrol"},
    {"id": 53,"name": "Mobil"}
  ],
```

And I have one more object called `items` and it has the below data

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": 1,"name": "Partsandservices","category_ids": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,"name": "Partsandservices","category_ids": "3,4,53"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,"name": "Shop","category_ids": null
    }
  ]
```

The goal I want to achieve is when I click on the `service_type` key `name` from the dropdown it should display items that will match with `category_ids` in the render. I am not able add the condition to `id` in `service_type` object and `category_ids` in `items`

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have control over that `items` object? Because `category_ids` should be an array not a comma separated string!

Comment: @Jamiec yes I have the control over it

Comment: Then start by changing it to an array - you'll thank me later

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would be good if you change the structure of category_ids to array, as suggested by Jamiec.

I would also suggest to return an empty array for categories, instead of null.

Once you do, when you select a category, you can query all products that are part of this category:

```
items.filter(item => (item.category_ids || []).includes(selectedCategoryId)
```

You didn't mention how the code looks for the actual dropdown selection, so I am assuming you already know how to get the id from the selected category.

If this collection will be getting large, I suggest to create a map structure (`key: category, value: item[]`), where you can list all items for a category. This way you will avoid querying all items every time you change a category.